# Python List of Tuples - Problems with intersection and union

Tags: python, list, tuples, union, intersection

Problem:

I want to construct a Query-Builder via URL. Return is list of Tuples, with the participants and participantdata. In database exists hundreds of participants with unique id. Every participant can have various participantdata. Each event registration creates a new participantdata in database, related the participant by email.

```
e.g.: include|eventid|is|17||include|eventid|is|13__include|unsubscribed|is|True
```

I seperate it into AND and OR queries.

AND's

```
1. include|eventid|is|17||include|eventid|is|13
2. include|unsubscribed|is|True
```

OR's

```
From first AND Condition: 
1. include|eventid|is|17
2. include|eventid|is|13
```

Result-Syntax:

```
[(participant_id, partidipantdata_id), (participant_id, partidipantdata_id), ...], 

e.g: [(123,1240), (123,959), (123,1124), (123,1450), (134, 1670), (156,1950), (123,1450), (156,2000), (220,2100), (234, 1754), (156,1121), (278,1556), (281,1671), (278,1771), (156,2111), (312,2254), (289,967), (278, 2178)]
```

Question:
· How can i combine (union) the OR-Queries correctly (participant_id, participantdata_id)?
--> The Query over various events needs the participant_id's, query over various events with unsubscribed (information who is stored in participantdata) needs the participantdata_id's
 Both is needed: participant_id and participantdata_id to get a end result query. 
 


**The Problem:** 
E.g. Query: event #17 AND event #13 AND all ParticipantDatas who have unsubscribed from this Events. (Result: 3 Queries with: Participants of #13 as well as #17 and alle Participants who had unsub on some event in system).

So i can do intersection the participant_id of 17 and 13. However to get all unsubs of this event, i have to do the intersection of the participantdata_id's of event #13 and event #17 and unsubs. But this will not work because every registration of event will create a new participantdata of an participant. participants who visited #13 and #17 will so not match. That's the problem!


· The Problem comes with the AND-Queries (intersection the result of the OR-Queries).

Thanks very much!
Chris

Comment: Please provide some more sample data that contains 123, 1240 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Return a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) of UID's for each record that match. Then you can use the `set`-objects built in union and intersection functions.

The UID needs to be unique for every possible result. In this case one possible result is a specific participant data, and it would be uniquely identified by (participant id, particiapant data id), so you can use that, meaning you could just return a `set` instead of a `list`.

Tuples are not the most efficient datatype here, but I don't think that matters for your case.

Comment: This is not work ... because for example the unsubscribe the participantdata ids are needed.

Comment: @user2543694: It works for that case as well. Please explain what is unclear and I will improve the answer.

Comment: the end result of the queries have to contain the participantdataids too. i need this information after the query and i can not get this by participant id. the participant id can have more than one participantdata ids ... so can't get the wished particpantdata id

Comment: @user2543694: OK, so the unique results aren't the participant ID. This was not obvious from your question. The point is that you make sets of unique ID's where each Unique ID responds to one possible result.  A tuple of (participantid, participantdataid) would work as a unique ID, so that' not a problem.

Comment: @user2543694: If what exactly? This is really quite trivial. How to make unions and intersections is in the docs I linked to. (You use `|` and `&` )

Comment: Okay operations like union and intersection with "normal" lists is clear. not so clear is your suggest in the post. given is a list with tuple pairs. but how can i get a list of UID's for every pair (participant id, participantdata id)?